# Sorting table rows by date comparing DateTime in seeds file and Date.now()

Tags: javascript, ruby, reactjs, sorting, date

I am trying to render a table with a list of appointment times that have a DateTime in my seeds file. I'm trying to sort them by date, and also conditionally render based on whether that time is in the past or future. I'm struggling to format it properly to be able to sort.

I've converted the array of objects from state so that every date attribute is in the Javascript date format.

Here is the relevant section:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class LessonsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current_time: Date.now(),
      lessons: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("current_user");
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/lessons/", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(lessons => {
        lessons.map(lesson => {
          lesson.timeslot.realdate = new Date(lesson.timeslot.realdate);
          return lesson;
        });
        this.setState({
          lessons
        });
      });
  }

  sortDates = () => {
    let sortedDates = this.state.lessons.sort(function(date, lesson) {
      return Date.now(date) - lesson.timeslot.realdate;
    });
    return sortedDates;
  };

  renderTableData = () => {
    // map over sorted array from separate function
    return this.state.lessons.length ? (
      this.sortDates().map(lesson => {
        console.log(lesson.timeslot.realdate > Date.now());
        return (
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{lesson.id}</th>
            <td>{lesson.teacher.name}</td>
            <td>
              {lesson.timeslot.month_name} {lesson.timeslot.date}
            </td>
            <td>{lesson.timeslot.hour}:00</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })
    ) : (
      <h6>'Loading'</h6>
    );
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.lessons);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="lesson-h1">Lessons</h1>
        <br></br>
        <div className="col-md-12 student-button-group"></div>
        <table className="table table-striped lesson-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Lesson ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Teacher</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Time</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.renderTableData()}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I think I need to sort by date and then map over what is returned to render the table rows. It's not seeming to have any effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function needs to return -1, 0, or 1 to work properly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort